# How to Enable USB Debugging from ADB or Recovery (Mobile Not bootable)?

Tags: adb, dpi, usb-debugging, screen-density, bootable

I set high value on DPI by mistake as result the Poco F3 to be non bootable. It can boot only to Safe Mode but I can't use the mobile because it doesn't appear all the screen. The problem is fixed as I thing via ADB but my USB Debugging has been disabled as results the ADB Commands to be failed. I want to find way to enable USB Debugging via ADB or Recovery (TWRP installed), except if somenone knows to change direct the DPI value throught System file which keeps the seting of DPI. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you must enable USB debugging in Android in the settings, before you can use it and there is no way around that.

Maybe [this](https://www.hardreset.info/de/devices/xiaomi/xiaomi-poco-f3/) directions will help you to reset your smartphone. Don't forget to save your data before if possible. Maybe you can connect to a PC via cable or read the data from a micro sd card.

Comment: Finally from "Adb devices" command by trying and other working device, I understand that the Usb debugging is enabled but in safe mode which I can boot, it is as Unauthorized. Does it have different if it would be Authorized ?

Comment: @Johnn78 It's been a while since I used adb, but if you authorized the PC before and checked "remember that selection" (or similar), then maybe it would work. I would recommend you just try it out.